# Node: Loop over lines of a file, process each asynchronously, wait for each result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a file of name and date-of-birth-info. For each line in the file, I need to submit the data to a web form and see what result I get. I'm using Node and Puppeteer (headless), as well as readline to read the file.

The code works fine for small files, but when I run it on the full 5000 names, or even a few hundred, I end up with hundreds of headless instances of Chromium, bringing my machine to its knees and possibly creating confounding timeout errors.

I'd prefer to wait for each form submission to complete, or otherwise throttle the processing so that no more than x names are in process at once. I've tried several approaches, but none does what I want. I'm not a JS whiz at all, so there's probably questionable design going on.

Any thoughts?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const BALLOT_TRACK_URL = 'https://www.example.com/ballottracking.aspx';
const VOTER_FILE = 'MailBallotsTT.tab';
const VOTER_FILE_SMALL = 'MailBallotsTTSmall.tab';
const COUNTY = 'Example County';


checkBallot = (async ( fName, lName, dob, county ) => {
  /* Initiate the Puppeteer browser */
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto( BALLOT_TRACK_URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });


  // fill out the form
  await page.type('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FirstNameText', fName );
  await page.type('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LastNameText', lName );
  await page.type('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DateOfBirthText', dob );
  await page.type('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CountyDropDown', county );

  let pageData = await page.content();

  // Extract the results from the page
  try {
  submitSelector = 'input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RetrieveButton"]';
  tableSelector  = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ResultPanel > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(7) > div';

  foundSubmitSelector = await page.waitForSelector(submitSelector, { timeout: 5000 } );
  clickResult = await page.click( submitSelector );
  foundTable = await page.waitForSelector(tableSelector, { timeout: 5000 } )

  let data = await page.evaluate( ( theSelector ) => {
    let text = document.querySelector( theSelector ).innerHTML.replaceAll('<br>', '').trim();
    /* Returning an object filled with the scraped data */
    return {
      text
    }
  }, tableSelector );
  return data;
} catch (error) {
  return {
    text: error.message
  }
} finally {
  browser.close();
}
});

const mainFunction =  () => {

  const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream( VOTER_FILE_SMALL ),
    output: null,
    console: false
  });
  
  readInterface.on('line', async(line) => {
    split = line.split( '\t' );
    fName = split[0];
    lName = split[1];
    dob = split[2];
    checkResult = await checkBallot( fName, lName, dob, COUNTY );
    console.log( line + '\t' + checkResult.text );
    to = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  });

};

mainFunction();
```

Comment: How using synchronous readLine on the file, and have the main function read and process just one line from the file at a time? On completion of each line, the main function calls itself again with a timeout 0. When the main function finally reaches the end of all the lines, it can exit without calling itself. If you want to overlap say 5 calls, you could start by calling the main function 5 times. Each time one of them finished, it would call the main function again to read the file and process the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that implements my suggestion in the comment. I have used a setTimeout to represent the async code that you have, but in principle the approach should be easily adaptable:

```
// Source file testReadFileSync.js

const fs = require( "fs" );

const data = fs.readFileSync( "./inputfile.txt", { encoding: "utf-8" } );
const lines = data.split( "\n" );
console.log( `There are ${lines.length} lines to process`);

var currentLine = 0;

function main(){
    // Check if we have processed all the lines
    if (currentLine == lines.length ) return;

    // get the current line number, then increment it;
    let lineNum = currentLine++;
    
    // Process the line
    asyncProcess( lineNum,  lines[ lineNum ] )

}


function asyncProcess( lineNum, line ){
    
    console.log( `Start processing line[${lineNum}]` );

    let delayMS = getRandomInt( 100 ) * 10
    setTimeout( function(){
        

        // ------------------------------------------------
        // this function represents all the async processing 
        // for one line.
        // After async has finished, we call main again
        // ------------------------------------------------

        console.log( `Finished processing line[${lineNum}]` );
        main();

    }, delayMS )

}

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

// Start four parallel async processes, each of which will process one line at a time
main();
main();
main();
main();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try. It looks as this will read the whole file into memory, but it's only about 5K lines so this should be fine. Thanks for taking the time to offer sample code -- I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: If you want to preserve the async operation on the file-reading side too, you could adapt your code to read lines asychronously into a [wait-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-queue), and have the processing function(s) read the next line from the queue instead of from the array.